# AJAX response cannot return 1 000 000 objects from spring mvc app

Tags: ajax, spring, asynchronous, model-view-controller, timeout

I would like to make GET request to controller in spring mvc and return 1 million of objects (to generate csv file from them and make user download it). This code works great for 500 000 , but when I increasing size to 700 000 or 1 mln of objects - it's NOT returning error or timeout, it goes to success() callback, but the response in NULL. Why it can happen ?

```
       A.$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url: 'getReport',
        dataType : "json",
        timeout : 10000000,
        success: function (response) { 
        alert(response);  // NULL
           }
```

Comment: This is bad way to web application do such things... Use pagination

Comment: @OlegYudovich but I need all the data to generate csv file, I'm not going to show it on the page. So there is no need to do pagination/ Why it's bad for app?

Comment: So Why just not generate your CSV on server side and request this file from client?

Comment: How is your data method to query the DB?

Comment: @JorgeSB my method to query DB  returns all needed data. In controller I can see this data. But when I returning it to ajax success() callback , the response is null. When it less than 700 000 objects, it returning all of them to js , when I increasing it to 800 000 - response is null

Comment: Could you show us the first record that generates the error, and the trace log of the error?